# How to align a view to right of another view with spacing?

Tags: android

I want to align my `View` to the right of another `View` but with some spacing between them. And I want to do this with `RIGHT_OF` rule. I have searched a lot but couldn't find proper solution.

Comment: use android:toRightOf="@+id/another_view"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the margin_left attribute or paddingLeft attribute for the second view as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/View1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/View2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/View1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="World" />


</RelativeLayout>
```